# PHP "UPDATE SET WHERE" is not throwing any errors but not working

Tags: mysql, null, sql-update

my php code (the only relevant part):

```
  $sql="UPDATE `posts` SET `likes`=`likes`+1 WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

is not working. i am trying to increment an int which is by default set to zero. the variable id is correctly set (a response from an html form) and the insert function works perfectly in the next line. I've researched this for a few hours but have come up empty handed :\ was wondering if anyone could assist me or point me in the right direction of a possible solution.

this is my query executed in the next line:

```
$res= $mysqli->query($sql);
```

$mysql being the database connection and $sql being the code snippet above.

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkIfb.png)

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around `$id`?

Comment: would taking those away effect the result? @GregSchmidt

Comment: By putting single quotes around it, you're turning it into a string, but I guess MySQL's okay with that. Still, seems weird, unless your id column is a GUID.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'll post a pic of my table structure on this as well to see if anything is wrong with that

Comment: `echo $sql;` and run it directly to see if it's the query. You should be binding parameters, which is what Greg Schmidt is referring; string interpolating it directly like you are (I would leave the quotes) is riskier, both in bad queries and the security issues related..

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is what prints "UPDATE `posts` SET `likes`=`likes`+1 WHERE `id`=10" (the id here happens to be 10)

Comment: Run it directly on MySQL and see if it updates what you think it should.

Comment: i did this, it does now it says 0 rows are effected which is weird @JaredFarrish

Comment: You need to run this query directly: `UPDATE posts SET likes=0 WHERE likes IS NULL`. Then your other query should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `NULL` allowance your table has for the integer column. I would recommend not using `NULL` on an integer column. For your current issue there are at least two ways to resolve it:

1. Use `coalesce` to select the value, or use `0` if it is null:

   update posts
   set likes = coalesce(likes, 0) + 1
   where id = 10;

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54d9ae/1

2. Update the row so it actually has a `0` value.

   ```
   update posts
   set likes = 0
   where id = 10;
   ```

... or you could just set it to `1` with that update. With this approach though you can take off the `where` clause and correct the whole table, assuming the `NULL` was incorrect.